# Is option_active_plugins actually doing anything useful?

Tags: plugins, rest-api, performance

I’m training to speed-up our `wp-json` responses, which are now spending approx 70% just on WordPress initialization. I searched the Internet and from the answers I found the **Must use plugins** with `option_active_plugins` is a recommended solution. In most cases [this very good article](https://deliciousbrains.com/comparing-wordpress-rest-api-performance-admin-ajax-php/) is also linked.

I implemented that solution but **I can’t see any noticeable speed improvement**. Further investigation showed that these plugins are **still initialized**. I also tried to disable our plugin (which handles `wp-json` requests) through it, but it **still accepts calls**!? Only change that I see is that plugins are marked as non active when I check the **Installed plugins** view in admin.

I’m testing on my local Windows based installation with 20+ plugins enabled on the WordPress v6.1.1 and PHP 7.4. I’m using a log file to track execution duration and make sure if they are executed. I’m comparing all enabled with no enabled plugins scenarios. To make sure I understand what’s going on, I also added `error_log()` lines to several wp core files and several other plugins.
At average it takes 1.6 seconds for WP to activate our rest handler, while our handler takes at average 250 ms to do its job and the values are the same if I use `option_active_plugins` or not.
But when I manually disable all plugins through admin, WP takes at average 400 ms to handover requests to our handler.

Am I missing something?

EDIT:
It's not clear from the text above - I'm using a bit modified function `hfm_exclude_plugins()` from the article which reduces plugins list passed with `option_active_plugins` filter. It is placed in the `mu-plugins` as a plugin file and it is executed before any other plugin has been initialized.

Comment: What's your actual code and where have you placed it? Are you using multisite?

Comment: I am using script from the article which filters option_active_plugins and I've saved it in the mu-plugins. It is executed as expected, before any other plugin init.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is alright with the `option_active_plugins`.

I accidentally placed `mu-plugins` in `plugins` and as it seemed to be activated correctly (and first) I was just blind to that issue.

Now the dynamic plugin deactivation works right and I am gaining significant speed improvement on my `wp-json` endpoints.

My bad :(

Sorry to all